# Cognos output file renaming to filesystem

Tags: unix, csv, cognos, renaming

So i have set up Cognos to Burst Reports to the unix filesystem.  I have set the CM.OUTPUTBURSTKEY param and this puts the burst reports in their seperate subdirectory.

However they are still named random things, ie 356_1416859122074.csv ...
Ideally id like this to be (whatever the burst key is)_(date).csv 
eg.  Organisation1_24nov2014.csv

Is this anyway to set this in cognos? or do i need to write a script?

IF i need to write a script i know that i can put it in the CM.OutputScript param...but will this run in each subdirectory of the the burstkeys?

thanks

Comment: Each output file will have an XML file with it that contains among other things the burst key.  You can use the language of your choice to parse that and rename the output file.

Comment: Thanks, Ive ended up trying to set up the renaming with the script on the IBM website..
Although im having more issues calling this script now but i will create a new post for that